# Standard Alternative for Compiler Specific Implementation of struct in union

Tags: c++

In Codeblocks, it allows Anonymous structs and it is quite useful as I've tried Unions and it does not work the same.

Now my question is that since it isn't standard, what would be the standard equivalent of:

```
typedef union Alpha
{
    uint32_t OuterInt;
    struct
    {
        unsigned char a, b, c, d, e, f;
    };
} *pAlpha;
```

See I cannot replace that anonymous struct with a union as it doesn't work the same. AND if I define the struct, and replace every call to it with StructName.a, StructName.b, etc.

Is there another way?

Comment: `struct`s don't have to have a name. Not even in C: One common pattern (in C, that is) is the following: `typedef struct { ... } Foo;`

Comment: What do you mean structs don't have a name :S

Struct Beta {}; has a name. Beta is the name of it. I reference my objects by a name. No?

The question is, how can I replace that inner struct with something equivalent and C++ standard. If I compile with -pedantic-errors, I it will not compile at all stating that: "warning: ISO C++ prohibits anonymous structs [-pedantic]"

Comment: look at the code. I don't see a name either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what would be the standard equivalent ?

Something like :

```
struct MyData
{
    unsigned char a, b, c, d, e, f;
};
union Alpha
{
    uint32_t OuterInt;
    MyData   data;

} *pAlpha;
```

Comment: Hmm this would require me to do something like this:

Alpha Meh; Alpha.data.a inorder to access member a. With the anonymous struct, I do: Alpha.a. Think of it like this:

typedef union XYZ
{
    uint32_t Color;
    struct
    {
        unsigned char X, Y, Z;
    };
} *PXYZ;

Passing this to a bitmap function (CreateDIBitmap) or something similar will work but passing what you suggested will cause an immediate crash. It would also require all functions using the previous version to now use data as the accessor like: Alpha.data.a